does Aggrid support header Name editing by double clicking the header name?
I am using aggrid in my angular application. I am trying to edit the header names from the UI like the rowData, simply by double clicking the header i wan to edit and proving with a new Header name. However i am dynamically producing my columnDefs from a json. So i dont have a default set of columnDefs. My columnsDefs will be different for different selected code from the dropdown.
I have not been able to even log the header name if i double click. Once i am able to capture the headername with adouble click it should be relatively simple from there.
